# C++, fstream objects passed to functions as reference, const?

Tags: c++, function, constants, pass-by-reference, fstream

I know that generally, references to data should be isolated as a constant within a function so that the function can't change it, does the same hold true for fstream objects that are only being used for input?

Such as...

```
void doFoo(fstream &fileName)
{
  fileName.open("data.txt", ios::in);
}
```

IF is it advisable, does it follow the same logic of most everything else?

Such as...

```
void doFoo(const fstream &fileName)
{
  fileName.open("data.txt", ios::in);
}
```

also curious about output streams as well

I'm just wondering if it matters, and if so, why?

thanks!

Comment: Try compiling the second. That's in addition to the error in both.

Comment: Short answer: no. You essentially always pass iostreams by non-const reference.

Answer (score 7):

The constantness of a file does not translate to the constant attribute of the object used to access the file. Even for just reading a file, you must modify internal buffers, the current read position etc. The same applies to output, so basically a const stream is not useful.

BTW: If you want to make clear that a function only reads from a stream, pass it a `std::istream&`. Firstly, the "i" in `istream` makes reasonably sure that you don't write to it. Secondly, the missing "f" of `fstream` allows the use with stringstreams, too, or streams like cin.

Comment: So, if I understand what you're saying, if I want to be absolute in my certainty of not contaminating the data of a file if all i'm doing is reading from it, use istream because it only opens it for input. Is that an accurate assessment of what you are saying?

Comment: Yes. `istream` does not have any `write`-functions. By using it, you achieve two things: First, your function's signature is telling the reader that it does not intend to modify the stream's contents. Second, such modifications are prevented by the compiler (unless you cast inside the function, which would be really bad style).

Answer (score 1):

If you pass an object (such as an `fstream` instance) as const reference, you can only invoke `const` member functions on it, such like:

```
// In some class declaration
void aConstMember(int a) const;
```

That is because such functions do not change the object's state, therefore the object can be `const`. Non-const member functions might modify member variables, so the object wouldn't be const anymore. Now if you look at the reference manual for `fstream`, you'll see that the `open()` member function is not a const one. So the second code example won't compile.

In general: Pass arguments of class type as `const &` unless they are going to be modified in the function. Opening a stream certainly *is* a modification. So just pass it by non-const reference.